# ZF2 - Always open with https?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework

I have following .htaccess but always my ZF2 site is not going to https but stays as http only.

when i open the site as `www.example.com or example.com or http://www.example.com or example.com/controller` i needed always it goes to `https://www.example.com` not stay in `http://` at all.

Why the following is not working?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: did you check if that https bit is actually being reached? Did you try moving it to BEFORE the other rules, in case that the `^.*$ [nc,l]` is trapping everything?

Comment: because that first `[nc,l]` line  matches **EVERYTHING** and terminates further processing, which means the index.php line is never reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following seems to work. Where i am telling

if visitor visit the site as below, then overwrite it always to https://

```
example.com
www.example.com
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
example.com/bla-bla
www.example.com/bla-bla
http://example.com/bla-bla
http://www.example.com/bla-bla
```

if visitor do have https:// then ignore the https overwrite

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: `!=on` is wrong. rewrite regexes DON'T use `=` for equality testing. the whole pattern is implicitly "equal". `=` has no special meaning, therefore you're literally testing `if(%{HTTPS} != "=on")`, which is ALWAYS true. it'll NEVER have a value of `=on`